# Calculating % in Pivot table - python

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, seaborn, heatmap

PS;- I tried fitting the outputs below here but didn't show nicely and it doesn't allow me to embed images hence link .

Problem - I am trying to calculate % win for a team against other team in game of cricket using python pivot table . I need to divide count of wins / count of matches . I got count of wins however i am unable to get count of matches in python pivot table

[complete data set link]---->[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fkPL.png)

heres the df.head() output ---->
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fkPL.png)

```
id  season       city   ...           umpire1        umpire2 umpire3
1   2    2017       Pune   ...    A Nand Kishore         S Ravi     NaN
2   3    2017     Rajkot   ...       Nitin Menon      CK Nandan     NaN
3   4    2017     Indore   ...      AK Chaudhary  C Shamshuddin     NaN
4   5    2017  Bangalore   ...               NaN            NaN     NaN
5   6    2017  Hyderabad   ...        A Deshmukh       NJ Llong     NaN
```

I converted it into pivot table with below code showing number of wins by team . Also calculated winner and losers

```
matches['loser'] = np.where(matches['winner']==matches['team1'],matches['team2'],matches['team1'])
func = lambda x: x.count()
b = pd.pivot_table(matches,index=['winner'],columns=['loser'],values=['id'],aggfunc = func,fill_value='0')

b
```

here’s the output [pivot table output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECb4e.png)

```
id         ...                            
loser                       Chennai Super Kings         ...         Sunrisers Hyderabad
winner                                                  ...                            
Chennai Super Kings                           0         ...                           4
Deccan Chargers                               4         ...                           0
Delhi Daredevils                              5         ...                           4
Gujarat Lions                                 0         ...                           0
Kings XI Punjab                               7         ...                           2
Kochi Tuskers Kerala                          1         ...                           0
Kolkata Knight Riders                         6         ...                           8
Mumbai Indians                               12         ...                           5
Pune Warriors                                 2         ...                           0
Rajasthan Royals                              6         ...                           4
Rising Pune Supergiant                        0         ...                           2
Rising Pune Supergiants                       0         ...                           1
Royal Challengers Bangalore                   7         ...                           4
Sunrisers Hyderabad                           2         ...                           0
```

then I put the output to heat map like so

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# Seaborn for plotting and styling
import seaborn as sns
#b=b.values
#plt.figure()
b=b.astype(int)
f,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13, 10))
ax=sns.heatmap(b,annot=True,ax=ax)
```

Comment: print(matches.head()), copy / paste and format with {} for both dataframes

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [`pd.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

**EDIT** - added step to order each team pair s.t. (A, B) & (B, A) are treated as the same pair

```
# Create copy from main DataFrame
df2 = df[['team1', 'team2']]
# Order the team pairs
index_swap = (df2['team1'] > df2['team2'])
df2.loc[index_swap, 'team1'], df2.loc[index_swap, 'team2'] = (
    df2.loc[index_swap, 'team2'], df2.loc[index_swap, 'team1']
)
# Create "win" column
df2['winner'] = (df2['team1'] == df['winner']) * 1.

# Generate win percentages per pair
win_percents = df2.groupby(['team1', 'team2'])[['winner']].mean()
b = pd.pivot_table(
    win_percents,
    index=['team1'],
    columns=['team2']
)
print(b)
```

Using the results from your `df.head()` snippet, my machine produces the following output:

```
team2      Delhi Hyderabad Kolkata Pune Punjab
team1                                         
Bangalore    1.0       0.0     NaN  NaN    NaN
Gujarat      NaN       NaN     0.0  NaN    NaN
Mumbai       NaN       NaN     NaN  0.0    NaN
Pune         NaN       NaN     NaN  NaN    0.0
```

*Note - copying the DataFrame data into a new frame `df2` seems unnecessary; I would like to see a solution that doesn't require this if anyone knows of such a solution.*

Comment: Thanks for your comment however this wont work as as intended . Scenario it will fail is when team 1 plays another match with team 2 but teams are switched for eg 
    38 Gujarat Lions Rising Pune Supergiant Rising Pune Supergiant
13 Rising Pune Supergiant Gujarat Lions Gujarat Lions.  In above case gujrat lion played as team 1 and lost and then played as team2 and won <br/> win pwercentage should be 50% each

Comment: I realized this as well; you’ll have to order the pairs first in the copied data. I’ll edit my post to do so later today.

Comment: additionally, this will only generate an "upper-triangular matrix" of values. you would need to do the extra step of filling in the "lower-triangle" from the upper values if having a mostly full table (minus the diagonal "team-A-vs-itself" cells) is what you want.